# ssh cronjob with while executes only 1 time

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, google-cloud-platform

I wrote a cronjob that should get snapshots by filter and regex and then run a while loop to delete all of them.

After the cronjob runs I see that only the first item deleted although it had to delete more.

This is the script:

```
*/5 * * * * sudo gcloud compute snapshots list --filter="creationTimestamp<$(date -d "-1 day" "+%Y-%m-%d")" --regexp "(.*my-instance-name.*)" --uri | while read SNAPSHOT_URI; do gcloud compute snapshots delete $SNAPSHOT_URI; done
```

I think the problem is that after the command it asks "Do you want to continue (Y/n)?"

Somewhy, for the first it is by default Y but maybe for the others, it waits to Y/n and that's why it deletes only the first.

Who can help me figure out how to fix it so that it will delete all the snapshots selected from the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -q for quite mode delete snapshot without asking y/n it may help

```
 */5 * * * * sudo gcloud compute snapshots list --filter="creationTimestamp<$(date -d "-1 day" "+%Y-%m-%d")" --regexp "(.*my-instance-name.*)" --uri | while read SNAPSHOT_URI; do gcloud -q compute snapshots delete $SNAPSHOT_URI; done
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to write -q at the end but it didn't work. And after the do gcloud it works fine.